# Generate WSDL schemalocation as HTTPS URL

Tags: wcf, https, wsdl

I have a WCF service that I have set up to be consumed via HTTPS.  Unfortunately when my client tries to consume it he immediately gets an error because the referenced schema locations generated in the WSDL are set as HTTP which throws an error when he tries to reference it in a client project.  Indeed from his network he cannot get to the XSD via the HTTP URL however, if he pastes the URL into a browser and changes the HTTP to HTTPS then he can see it.

So is there anyway that I can specify the proper generation of the URL, i.e. as HTTPS?

FYI... Our environment does not use SSL or certs, using WAF and a proxy instead.

Comment: Tell your client to use REST and be done with it.  Web API, EASY.  Setup webhttp REST endpoints on your service.  Why the heck people wanna still deal with verbose and painful wsdl as we can see is not that "easy" as there are many pains with setting this crap up is beyond me.  Most people are and have been using simple REST calls over the wire.  Go ask a java or non .NET guy about wsdl and they'll want to beat you up for using it.  There are ALWAYS pains with managing and maintaining and setting up wsdl garbage no matter what your boss, lead, architect tells you.  It;s why MS got rid of WCF

Comment: BWT, I have the same stupid problem, I'm being forced to support both WSDL and REST which is just stupid.  So I have the same problem as you above, with these freakin wsdl definitions at the moment.  I could have move on by now if people would just freakin call our service RESTfully and use the ASP.NET Web API!  Sorry I am just sick of stupidity, people thinking wsdl is still an ok way to go, it isn't.  I am angry today :(